# Message logging for REST calls in eWam

Tags: rest, logging, ewam

Is there any way to enable/disable message logging for REST calls in eWamEx? We had this functionality for Soap calls in WIConfig.xml file.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by message logging? header or body information? Is it in case of status 200 or other? Do you have any example of API call?

Comment: @ Damien, Yes. I meant logging the body/payload of incoming and outgoing REST call, into a text file. Ideally, this helps when an external consumer reports an issue with the calls he/she had made. This way, we can get hold of exact request and response from the log files which were involved in the reported issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're talking about this kind of message logging:

```
PREPROCESSOR detected aWT_DefaultProcessor.AllowCORS
PREPROCESSOR detected aWT_DefaultProcessor.FilterSystemVars
PREPROCESSOR detected aWFX_GenericWynsureAuth.SignInUser
```

It will enable/disable by setting `/ERRORMESSAGE` to true/false from *`WedRPCServer` command line*.

If you want to know how to get the complete request/response like message logging of `WIConfig.xml`, there is actually no option for this in `eWamEx`.
But you can get them from code by using `aWT_HttpRequest.AsText` or `aWT_HttpResponse.AsText`.